# css class won't change existing class properties

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a li styled as follows:

```
#app-container ul.apps li.app1 {
   border-color:#57b6dd;
   background:url(app-icons/app1.png) no-repeat 10px 10px;
}
```

`<li class="app1">`

Now suppose I have the same li appear again in the page, but I want to change the border colour to tray, adding a class to the existing class doesn't change the colour.

```
.app-inactive-border { 
   border-color: #666666;
}
```

`<li class="app1 app-inactive-border">`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

I've put it up on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/noscirre/JtVGp/24/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.app-inactive-border` is less [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) then `#app-container ul.apps li.app1`

Where multiple rule-sets provide rules which change the same property, the most specific rule-set wins.

Use `#app-container ul.apps li.app1.app-inactive-border`

Comment: I'm not positive on this which is why i'm not submitting as an answer, but wouldn't marking it as important override the other rules? *EDIT* my bad, just read the other answer and it mentions important

Comment: It would, but `!important` is evil. It is a one shot hammer that tends to put you in a position of having to use a more specific selector *and* important later on.

Comment: okay thanks for the reply. I haven't used !important at all i just have a general idea of what it is for. It seems like it is not best practice though. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to do this :

```
.app-inactive-border { border-color: #666666!important; }
```

its juste to know what is the role of "!important".
but Quentin answer is a best practice ans more readable syntax.

```
last thing : you can simplify the hexa color code like this #666;
```